# Using TempData Several

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a mvc page that named UploadFile with their actions and view. In my actions, I used TempData to send from one to another for reusing of my excel list when the view is refreshed. It worked when going from the first page to the second page of grid. However after second refresh, tempdata disappeared and I got an empty grid again.

How can I keep and reuse my TempData until pass another view/action.

```
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult UploadFile()
        {
            return View("UploadFile", TempData["Veri"]);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult UploadFile(HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {
            try
            {

                string _FileName = string.Empty;
                string _path = string.Empty;
                List<ImportExcelDto> listExcel = new List<ImportExcelDto>();


                if (file.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    _FileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                    _path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads"), _FileName);

                    string tempfolder = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads");


                    var fileGeneration = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads"));
                    fileGeneration.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList().ForEach(f => f.Delete()); //Directory'deki eski excel dosyalarını temizler

                    file.SaveAs(_path);
                }
                ViewBag.Message = "Dosya Başarıyla Aktarıldı!";

                DataTable dt = Helpers.GetDataTableFromExcel(_path, true);

                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    ImportExcelDto item = new ImportExcelDto() { KartNo = dt.Rows[i][0].ToString(), Tutar = dt.Rows[i][1].ToDecimal() };
                    listExcel.Add(item);
                }

                var TempDataVeri = listExcel;
                TempData["Veri"] = TempDataVeri;
                return View("UploadFile", listExcel);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ViewBag.Message = "Dosya Aktarılamadı!";
                return View();
            }
       }
```

Comment: I'm confused why you want to use temp data multiple times?  You could pull out the object instantiation outside the post function, but that would by pass the verification process and multiple clients could get the same objects mixed up.  I think you need to tell us understand your end goal before I can answer the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `KEEP` and `PEEK`

example :

```
object value = TempData.Peek("value");

object value = TempData["value"];
//later on decide to keep it
TempData.Keep("value");
```

This will help you to keep the data for more than 1 access/request.

Usually Once you access the `TempData` it gets deleted

You can use `Peek` when you always want to retain the value for another request. Use `Keep` when retaining the value depends on additional logic.

Comment: It worked, mate. Many thanks for your helpful and quick reply!

Comment: I marked it mate, however I can't upvote your answer because my account is fresh. Thanks for peek-keep info.

Comment: That's ok :) glad it helped

Answer (score 0):

`TempData` keeps the information for the time of an `HTTP Request`. This mean only from one page to another. This also works with a 302/303 redirection because it’s in the same `HTTP Request`. It helps to maintain data when you move from one controller to other controller or from one action to other action.

You can use `Session` to keep the value for long time.

```
Session["Veri"] = TempDataVeri;
```

Comment: Better to keep the tempdata for more than 1 request

Comment: But he wants to maintain the data for more than one request.

Comment: yes you can use TempData for multiple request as well

Comment: Yes but he is facing issue with `TempData` and with `Session` it can be resolved.

Comment: well mvc's idea was to remove session that why they created viewbag, viewdata and tempdata

Comment: Also OP question states use TempData several times/ more than 1 time

Comment: MVC doesn't remove session but new architecture on cloud, web farm(due to multiple machines used for hosting) etc make imperative to use out-proc session which is not in memory on same machine so avoid wherever possible. Both are correct about TempData so +1 for both :)

Comment: @PranavSingh what i meant was to reduce the direct usage of session

Comment: @PranavSingh another thing as per my understanding TempData is in the memory untill its being used and doesn't depend upon request means its available for 3rd request as well if its not used in first 2 request, kindly correct me if i'm wrong